# Matplotlib: Overriding "ggplot" default style properties

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-ggplot

I am using matplotlibs *ggplot* style for plotting and want to overide only specific standard parameters such as the color of the xticklabels, grid background color and linewidth.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

# changing matplotlib the default style
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

# dataframe plot
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(36, 3))
df.plot()
```

returns:
[image]

I know I can set single properties for axes-objects like this:

```
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('red')
```

But how can I override the default propertiers (e.g. label-color, background color and linewidth to have them in **all** plots?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [`rcParams`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) to set parameters globally. e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# changing matplotlib the default style
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth']=3
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor']='b'
plt.rcParams['xtick.color']='r'

# dataframe plot
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(36, 3))
df.plot()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Is there any way to globally change the axis label color?

Comment: in the link from my answer it shows everything you can change. for axis labels, you can use `plt.rcParams['axes.labelcolor']='r'`. Not sure if you can change x and y separately

Comment: Perfect. You saved my day. Thanks a lot!!